# Finding rigid 2D transformation of a small set

Tags: c++, opencv, vision

I want to fit small set of lines to a large set of lines (obtained from image) with translation and rotation only.

After converting the lines to points, I tried using cv::estimateAffinePartial2D() which should do the job, but it has an assert requiring the source and target sets to be of the same size.

Ideas why is that?
Recommendations on how to do that, besides going over all possible subsets?

Answer (score 1):

> After converting the lines to points[...]

you simply need to extract more points from the smaller set of lines ( or fewer points from the bigger set of lines, or a combo of both ) in order to give the same number of points to estimateAffinePartial2D(). Equivalently, given that you want an affine xform, you could just pseudorandomly decimate the bigger points source according to some spatially homogeneous distribution ( assuming homogeneously distributed outliers ).

Comment: i have 5 lines on the small set and around a 100+ lines on the large set, are you sure resampling is recommended here? why is the same size assertion there anyway?

Comment: @EranGeva re the same size requirement, you should ask the estimateAffinePartial2D author; moreover, that requirement is not even documented in the function doc. Anyway, it's required by Levenberg–Marquardt solver.

Comment: @EranGeva re resampling, it's your responsability to ensure that resampling does not bias the result.

Comment: i found the assert when i went into the code at the end of https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/ptsetreg.cpp . i will try your suggestion, thank you.

Comment: @EranGeva I see, both the LM and the RANSAC solvers assert for equal input sizes; anyway, note that even if opencv supported differently sized inputs, internally it would always resample them ( either explictly or implictly ) hence possibly introducing some bias. However you put it, you still need special care to avoid biasing the result given very differently sized dependent/indipendent sets.